# Using the result that is generated later on the first page

Tags: exam, variable, gradetable

The exam class allows one to generate a gradetable that is dynamically generated depending on the number of questions, like so

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\begin{document}
\multirowgradetable{1}[questions]
\begin{questions}
    \question[10] First question
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
\end{questions}
```

which gives this:
[image]

As this table is too wide, exam gives the option to display multiple tables instead:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\begin{document}
\multirowgradetable{2}[questions]
\begin{questions}
    \question[10] First question
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
\end{questions}
```

which produces
[image]

I want the number of tables to be dynamically generated, so that I have a table for each 10 exercises. I tried this using the calculator package:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{calculator}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question[10] First question
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
\end{questions}
\INTEGERDIVISION{\numquestions}{10}{\sola}{\solb}
\ADD{\sola}{1}{\numrows}
\multirowgradetable{\numrows}[questions]
\end{document}
```

This works as long I put the table at the end of the document. But I want it at the beginning. What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the number of questions at end document in the aux file, so to allow to have the number available at the beginning of the next run.

One table is produced if the number of questions is up to eight, otherwise two tables are produced.

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifdefined\exam@numquestions
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\total@questions{\exam@numquestions}}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\total@questions}[1]{\gdef\totalquestions{#1}}
\providecommand{\totalquestions}{1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\multirowgradetable{%
  \ifnum\totalquestions<9 1\else 2\fi
}[questions]

\begin{questions}
    \question[10] First question
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
    \question[10] Another
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output when only eight questions are provided.

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank  you!